# existence and uniqueness of solution of a system of linear equation

Tags: matrices

I read the following Theorem
"A linear system is consistent if and only if the rightmost column of the augmented matrix is not a pivot column..."
But why is that? the following augmented matrix have a rightmost pivot column and there is a sloution

$\ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & -9 & 12 & -9 & 6 &15 \\
0& 2 & -4& 4& 2& -6 \\
0 & 0 & 0& 0&1&4 \end{array} \right)$

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are misreading the statement. Of course, there is always a rightmost pivot column - just look at all the pivot columns and see which one is farthest right. The theorem says to look at the rightmost column overall - in this case $\begin{pmatrix} 15 \\ -6 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$ - and see if it's a pivot column. Here, the pivot columns are $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} -9 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$, so the system is consistent.

Comment: I see that means that on the B column there is a a pivot number therefore there is an equation $0x=B$